# Magento 2.3 inserts admin/ in url when saving product

Tags: product, magento2.3, backend

I get this behavior when saving product in admin area, my url is:

```
domain.com/mybackend/catalog/product/edit/id/1628...
```

when I save product I get this url:

```
domain.com/admin/mybackend/catalog/product/edit/id/1628...
```

it `returns 404`, if I remove admin/ from url I get correct backend page and product is correctly saved, someone can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use setUrl to redirect to this page

```
$resultRedirect->setUrl('/mybackend/catalog/product/edit/id/1628');
return $resultRedirect;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm getting this behavior for any product in database, How to debug?